# Xamarin Android get privateExternalStorage with GetExternalFilesDir()

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an app that needs to create a file in an app-specific directory, but that file need to be public so it can be edited by another app, so I need a path like this `"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.app/files"`

I already checked [Xamarin Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows) and I found what I need. Based on that Documentation I can use this method `Android.Content.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(string type)`.

But I get this error when I call that method.

`An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Context.GetExternalFilesDir(string)'`

I also already check [this forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7499/android-content-getexternalfilesdir-is-it-available) but found no luck

Any ideas how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get privateExternalStorage you can use this

`Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null).AbsolutePath;`

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: yeah, thank you for the reminder. Actually, I have to wait for 2 days to be able to accept my own answer